# Payment module return URI

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating a payment module for our payment gateway...

So far I have 1) set up the back-end and 2) used the hookPayment() method to display a hidden form at part 5 of the checkout process (http://prestashop.dev/order). This will then redirect off to my gateway with all the required information. Good job.

The next part is the part I am struggling with. I don't understand what the return URIs are for payment-confirmation - just to give the customer some information on the status of the order (and maybe also update the back-office?).

For now, I have just a very simple method;

```
public function hookPaymentReturn()
{
  // if (!$this->active) {
  //     return null;
  // }

  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/confirmation.tpl');
}
```

in my main module file. I just want to get to this on the browser... I'll start worrying about POST'ed values after this. But for now I just don't know the URI. What will it be?? Do I need to register the route somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Most payment modules `confirmation.tpl` get hooked into the `order-confirmation.tpl` of your theme which in turn gets called by the `OrderConfirmationController.php`.

This can be accessed by:

`[YOUR_BASE_URL]/index.php?controller=order-confirmation&[some_stuff]`.

The `[some_stuff]` part is important though since the controller performs a series of validations and will redirect you somewhere else if these are not met

Comment: Just to test this I tried a test to by by cheque and the return url was `http://prestashop.dev/order-confirmation?id_cart=15&id_module=30&id_order=12&key=25c97e1d2157ba33402a5512ade3beeb`. So that's not the same as what you've said

Comment: right that's the rewritten url for accessing the order-confirmation controller. Since there's no way for me to know to what you, or anyone else, has changed the friendly url for order-confirmation i used the direct way to access the controller. Just try the url i posted with the params you just posted, i'm pretty sure you will get the same confirmation page

Comment: but I can call the controller name whatever I like, right? If I create `GatewayFoobarModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController` class then I can access the `postProcess` method just by passing `controller=foobar`. So what is the point? Do I just do all my validating there? I don't actually have to follow the convention?

Comment: Even I can see these are bad questions I am asking :(